# How to split the comma separated data in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I have below dataframe :

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123, 124 | Employer, Employer | EAGLE, ANIMAL |

If you see above data, three columns have comma separated data. First value from Col 2 is connected to col3 first data and col 4 first data . That is col3 value for col2 - 123 is Employer and col4 value is EAGLE. Similarly, col3 value for col2 - 124 is Employer and col4 value is ANIMAL. I want to split the above data in below tabular format:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | Employer | EAGLE |
| 1 | 124 | Employer | ANIMAL |

I have tried with explode and split for each col2 , col3 and col4 and got below result which is not matching with expected one.

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | Employer | EAGLE |
| 1 | 123 | Employer | ANIMAL |
| 1 | 124 | Employer | EAGLE |
| 1 | 124 | Employer | ANIMAL |

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing `array_zip` then `explode`.

```
cols = ['col2', 'col3', 'col4']

df = (df.select('col1', *[F.split(c, ',').alias(c) for c in cols])
      .select('col1', F.arrays_zip(*[F.col(c) for c in cols]).alias('cols'))
      .select('col1', F.explode('cols').alias('cols'))
      .select('col1', 'cols.*'))
```